# login to WPEngine Git Push with Tower Git

Tags: wordpress, git, ssh, private-key, git-tower

I've set up my developer name and public key on WPEngine's Git Push dashboard. i'm able to connect via the terminal:

```
$ ssh git@git.wpengine.com info
    hello <my wpengine dev name>
    R W production/my_installname
    R W staging/my_installname
```

so it all looks to be set up correctly.

but when trying to connect with Tower Git client, i'm getting the error:

> Can't Authenticate with Server Authentication with the server failed.
>   Please verify your username and password.

for the Tower login, i'm using:

**Remote URL**: git@git.wpengine.com:production/my_repo.git

**Authentication**: Private Key

**Username**: (i tried my dev name and my email address, neither worked)

**SSH**: ~/.ssh/id_rsa (which i generated for WPEngine, and uploaded the associated public key)

i've tried all different combinations of usernames and URLs, etc. nothing is working. any ideas? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Prerequisite

From your question I gather you're on macOS, most likely macOS 10.12 which stopped autoloading SSH keys into the keychain and creating this situation. 
However, the Walkthrough is valid for all OS/Tower versions.

### Use Tower's Service Interface to prepare SSH key loading

Navigate to Tower's service view with `Cmd+Ctrl+S`.
In the bottom left click the `+` to choose "Add Custom Server"

As authentication information enter

Server name: `ssh://git@git.wpengine.com`
Choose SSH Key authentication and enter your credentials

#### Cloning Repositories

Should now work as expected

#### Existing Repositories - make sure they're linked to your Service

Open your repository in Tower, click your remote in the sidebar (most likely `origin`)
Hover the `Fetch URL` to reveal the "Edit" button
Press it and make sure your Custom Service is selected in this dialog
Test by clicking "Fetch"

You can find out more about connecting/authenticating the official Tower help:
https://www.git-tower.com/help/mac/manage-hosting-services/manage-ssh-keys
https://www.git-tower.com/help/mac/remote-repositories/connect-authenticate

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm with the support team for Tower</sub>

Comment: make sure the username is "git". not you dev name in WPE.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this while trying to add my wpengine repositories to Tower and had to try a few different URLs before getting the correct one. The connection is specific to the repository not the account, unlike in the terminal.

This URL scheme worked: `ssh://git@git.wpengine.com/production/repo.git`

The username in the form field is `git` and you select the correct SSH key in the dropdown (just as Samuel stated above). Obviously, the only difference is adding the path to the repo; but I tried a few options with port numbers and different URL schemes that didn't work so I thought I'd post to save anyone else the hassle of figuring it out in 2019.